# Spivak's Calculus - Chapter 1 Question 1.3

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-verification

I'm reading through Spivak's Calculus, and am not sure where to start in proving the following:

> if $x^2 = y^2$, then $x = y$ or $x = -y$

Particularly given that only the following properties can be used to justify each step of the proof:

[image]
[image]

Any hints on how to start would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

P7 implies that if $ab=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$. Various of the others show that if $x^2=y^2$ then $(x+y)(x-y)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! P7 addresses when a·b =1. How can I formally go from P7 to a statement about conditions under which ab =0?

Comment: No, P7 addresses something else. Actually the P7 as stated in the book is poorly phrased. The real P7 is this: "If $x \ne 0$ there exists $y$ such that $xy=1$; we define $x^{-1}=y$." Now if $a\ne0$ and $b\ne0$ then $(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})=1$, hence $ab\ne 0$, because $0x=0$ for every $x$. (Now you have to prove $0x=0$. This follows from $0x=(0+0)x$...)

Comment: The road I'm currently on in this proof, I need to use the property that $a·0=0$ but I'm not seeing that in chapter one. :(

Comment: Although, Spivak does use the assumption that $a·0=0$ on page six of the fourth edition without ever listing that as a fundamental proposition. I guess if he can run with it, so can I. :/

Comment: I gave you a hint how to show $a0=0$. Since $0+0=0$, $a0=a(0+0)=a0+a0$, and that implies $a0=0$.

Comment: Right. Just spotted that on page seven as well. Phew.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. First use the properties given to show that if the product of two numbers is $0$ then at least one of them is $0$. Then factor $x^2 - y^2$.

(For real back-to-the-axioms rigor you'd have to show why that factoring is legal.)

**Edit** to expand on the hint. Suppose
$$
ab = 0
$$
and $a \ne 0$.
Then use P7 to find an inverse for $a$ and multiply through by that to show $b=0$. Justify each step with an appeal to the axioms. You'll need P5 and P6.

Comment: Thank you! P7 addresses when a·b =1. How can I formally go from P7 to a statement about conditions under which ab =0?

Comment: @StudentsTea See my edit.